# how to prevent illustrator to take line as a path with text

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a question about a type tool and lines. In my case Illustrator is used to draw isobar lines on a map (similar to this image I randomly picked from the web as an example):

[image: map]

With isobars there is a number written near the line two end-points. But when trying to write a number there, and doing that close enough to the line, the Illustrator activates automatically "write to path" and the isobar line goes transparent, goes missing.

Is there a way to tell illustrator not to use that line as a path so that i could write close enough to the line and not activate the "write to path" (maybe holding some key down when writing?).

The alternative would be to write a little further from the line and move it closer with a selection tool later. But this is another move that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but there are a number of things you can do.

As you said, create the type away from the line and move it in to position after. Or, the easiest solution is to work on another layer and lock the layer with the isobar lines. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use it to your advantage. See the isobar does disappear but its not gone you can use the direct select tool (white arrow, <kbd>A</kbd>) and reapply a stroke to the path. The benefit of this is that you dont duplicate the data so changing things later is more fun. But it is a very annoying workflow.